# can't access the values throw the eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a post model and like model and I make a relationship between them but still can't access the values of the like model through the post

that is the like model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Like extends Model
{
    
     protected $guarded = [];


     
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Post::class);
    }
}
```

and that is the post modal

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Laravelista\Comments\Commentable;

class Post extends Model
{

    use Commentable;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
    }
}
```

this is the like Migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateLikesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('like')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('dislike')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('likes');
    }
}
```

and that the output when I try to access the data
I can access the relationship but can't access the rest of the data

```
$t->likes
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4667
     all: [
       App\Like {#4654
         id: 1,
         user_id: 1,
         post_id: 1,
         like: 1,
         dislike: 2,
         created_at: "2021-05-21 16:49:39",
         updated_at: "2021-05-21 16:49:39",
       },
     ],
   }
>>> $t->likes-like
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant like - assumed 'like' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in E:/files/workshop/projects/iraqm-maineval()'d code on line 1
```

Comment: [LIKE is a reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). You may want to change the name of the column slightly to prevent confusion.

Comment: Typo: `$t->likes-like` vs. `$t->likes->like`

Comment: but i try to access the id and get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- when ever you see yourself using hasOne relationship think of creating a field !
- if you have a like and a dislike and no relationship those are 3 possibilities of interaction of the user on the post so it would be efficient if you have exactly a combination of 3 possibilities of data in your db .

> record exists => there an interaction : 0 for dislike and 1 for like . 
> record does not exist => there is no interaction .

in your code you used like and dislike fields which means you have 4 possibilités which doesnt make any sense since we only need 2 ( and the does not exits ) .
i would recommand to change your migration for less queries and tests , remove the like model and use model method (likes , liked ..)

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->foreignId('user_id');
            $table->foreignId('post_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('like')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Post Model

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function likes()
    {   
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'likes', 'post_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('like')
    }
}
```

User Model

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function likes()
    {   
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'likes', 'user_id', 'post_id')->withPivot('like')
    }

    
}
```

Like Controller

```
public like(Post $post) {
     $like = Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id' , $post->id)->first();
     if($like) {
           if($like->pivot == 1) {
                 $like->delete(); 
           }else {
                 $like->like = 1;
                 $like->save();
           }
     }else {
         
        Auth::user()->create(['post_id'=>$post->id , 'like'=>1])
        
      }
}


// same for dislike ,, you can refactor in multiple model methods
```

Comment: i try your code but i run into this error ``` Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\HasMany::withPivot() ```

Comment: @Monty please try it again , and i will advise you to revise the code before applying it since i didnt copy it froim any where , i was giving you the strategy .. and you could be using a different laravel version . finally it should be belongsToMany

Comment: i updated the question btw thats why i said try again , i thought i already said that i updated xd sorry xd

Comment: don't worry I understand you

Comment: what are you facing now ?

Comment: I do some changes and now it's work thanks again@HijenHEK